# delete operation in C++

Tags: c++, new-operator, dynamic-memory-allocation, delete-operator

I don't understand what `delete` means.

For example, in the code below, `delete ptr;` so the `pointer variable ptr` is deleted or `the memory ptr pointed to` is deleted?

```
int *ptr = new int; 
*ptr = 7;  
delete ptr;
```

Comment: memory ptr pointed to is deleted

Comment: so there is no 7 anymore right?

Comment: There probably still is a `7` somewhere, but the space it occupies will be reused by a further allocation in the long run, so its days are counted.

Comment: Perhaps read the book again

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> so the pointer variable ptr is deleted or the memory ptr pointed to is
>   deleted?

**The memory pointed to** by `ptr` is *deleted* (i.e. marked as free - the contents could still be there, but, as @JonTrauntvein also mentioned, depending on the implemetation that memory could be overwritten with a certain pattern as well - it should never be accessed after a delete).

**The pointer itself** doesn't change and still contains the same value (i.e. the memory address it was pointing to), but it is a good habit to *null* the pointer after deletion, i.e. `ptr = NULL;`.

This memory was allocated on the heap with `new int` and should always be freed with `delete`.

---

```
int *ptr = new int;
```

-> memory is allocated on the heap - amount: `sizeof(int)` - `ptr` points to that memory location.

```
*ptr = 7;
```

-> the value `7` is placed in that allocated memory.

```
delete ptr;
```

-> The allocated memory (containing 7) is *deleted* (i.e. marked as free for other usage). `ptr` still points to that freed memory location. Accessing it is invalid, so the pointer should be set to `NULL`.

Comment: The pointer variable `ptr` still has the same value after the call to `delete`, it just no longer points to an `int`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - Indeed - added some extra info.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the memory pointed to prior to the call to delete will be untouched by the delete operator.  Some implementations, such as the visual c++ debug run time library, will overwrite the memory with a recognisable pattern which sometimes help to recognise when you are attempting to access deleted memory.

Comment: @JonTrauntvein - That's right. Added it to the post - thanks.